# Is that possible navigator.userAgent not exist for a browser?

Tags: javascript, browser

I read `userAget` of the browser with `navigator.userAgent` and send back to my backend. When I analyze userAgents, I found it was not sent for some browser. Is that possible some browsers do not have `navigator.userAgent`? If yes, how can I find out browser information?

Comment: Surely it's possible. Moreover you shouldn't rely on userAgent info.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Why do you need browser information?

Comment: it is possible, example: `curl`

Comment: headless chrome and most of the website crawling tools (ex puppeteer) don't have userAgent by default